# Show that there exists a $q \in \Bbb Q$ such that $x < q < y$ for $x, y \in \Bbb R$ and $x < y.$

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen a solution for this but I'm having trouble understanding the reasoning.

The solution says the following;

> Let $N$ be a positive integer such that $N > \frac{1}{y-x}$. Then the difference between successive members of the sequence $\ldots, \frac{-2}{N},\frac{-1}{N}, 0, \frac{1}{N}, \frac{2}{N}, \ldots$ is less than $y-x$, $\textbf{and so $x < q < y$}$ for at least one rational number $q = \frac{M}{N} .$

I see that the difference between each member of the sequence is $\frac{1}{N}$ and so from the choice of $N$ it's obvious that $\frac{1}{N} < y-x$, but I'm not sure why this automatically means that there exists such a $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the set $ S=\{ k\in {\Bbb Z} : k/N\leq x \}$.
Show that $S$ has a maximum $m$. What can you say about $(m+1)/N$ ?

Comment: Hmm, still struggling.. doesn't $x = \max S$? In which case $$x < x + \frac{1}{N} < y$$

which would be fine if $x$ were just rational. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: No, the set is clearly bounded from above so has a max $k\in Z$ for which $k/N\leq x$ (they may be equal if $x$ is rational, but need not be). In any case $(m+1)/N > x$ and at the same time $(m+1)/N < y$ or else you run into a contradiction with the definition of  $N$.

Comment: Indeed, I've just added an answer of my own to the question after understanding. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your final argument is perfect!

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there are some details left to verify from this solution, although it seems intuitively correct. Here is an argument that fills in the details, using the axiomatic properties of $\mathbb{R}$.

We will show that there exists $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x < \frac{m}{N} < y$. Suppose not. Suppose for each $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ either $\frac{m}{N} \leq x$ or $\frac{m}{N} \geq y$. Then we can decompose $\mathbb{Z} = A \cup B$, where

$$
A = \{m\in \mathbb{Z} : \frac{m}{N} \leq x \}
$$
and 
$$
B = \{m\in \mathbb{Z} : \frac{m}{N} \geq y \}.
$$

Then $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Since $B$ is bounded from below, it has a least element, $m_0$ (this follows from the Completeness Axiom for $\mathbb{R}$ and the definition of what an integer is).

Then since $m_0$ is the least element in $B$, $m_0 - 1 \notin B$. By the way we decomposed $\mathbb{Z}$, it must be that $m_0 -1 \in A$. So

$$
\frac{m_0-1}{N} \leq x < y \leq \frac{m_0}{N},
$$

by the definition of $A$ and $B$. Rearranging, you will get the contradiction to the fact that $y-x > \frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: Why is A bounded from below?

Comment: It's not. I got my $A$ and $B$ mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

From H. H. Rugh's hint, if $m$ is the maximum element of $S = \{k \in \Bbb Z : \frac{k}{N} \leq x \}$ then $ x < \frac{m+1}{N}$. Additionally, $\frac{m + 1}{N} < y$, which we can see because $\frac{m+1}{N} - \frac{m}{N} < y - x$, from how we chose $N$. Hence, there is always a $q = \frac{M}{N}$ such that $x < q < y$.

Comment: Do you not want $x < (m+1)/N$ rather than $x < m + \frac{1}{N}$?

Comment: $m = \frac{l}{N}$, I just changed up the notation a bit :)

Comment: Thanks, I liked your answer too. Good to have several answers :)

Comment: On second thought, what is $l$? The maximum of $S$ should be an integer. Is $\frac{l}{N}$ an integer?

Comment: The answers are essentially the same, I just put in more details.

Comment: $\frac{l}{N}$ is chosen to be the maximum element of $S$. Why should $\max S$ be an integer?

Comment: $S$ is a subset of the integers.

Comment: Is it not a subset of the rationals?

Comment: No, the elements of $S$ are all of the integers $k$ such that $\frac{k}{N} \leq x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44575/discussion-between-ed-4434-and-cat).